# can't receive webhooked data

Tags: php, json

I am trying to use webhook to receieve data from a sms service provider.the hooked URL is http://exmple.com/xy/myphp.php and my myphp.php is as follows:

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("server","uname","pass","db");
error_reporting(0);
$request = $_REQUEST["data"];
$jsonData = json_decode($request,true);

foreach($jsonData as $key => $value)
{
    // request id
    $requestID = $value['requestId'];
    $userId = $value['userId'];
    $senderId = $value['senderId'];
    foreach($value['report'] as $key1 => $value1)
    {
        //detail description of report
        $desc = $value1['desc'];
        // status of each number
        $status = $value1['status'];
        // destination number
        $receiver = $value1['number'];
        //delivery report time
        $date = $value1['date'];

        $sql="INSERT INTO `delivary_report`(`request_id`, `user_id`, `sender_id`,`date`,`receiver`,`status`,`description`) VALUES('$requestID','$userId','$senderId','$date','$receiver','$status','$desc')";
        $res=$con->query($sql);
    }
}
//echo $request;

?>
```

the sms service provider is saying that they can get 406 error. please tell me how to solve this issue. currently i am using godaddy shared server. the json formated data they are sending looks like the follows.

```
data=[
      {
          "requestId":"35666a716868323535323239",
          "userId":"38229",
          "report":[  
              {  
                  "desc":"REJECTED",
                  "status":"16",
                  "number":"91XXXXXXXXXX",
                  "date":"2015-06-10 17:09:32.0"
              }
          ],
          "senderId":"tester"
      },
      {  
          "requestId":"35666a716868323535323239",
          "userId":"38229",
          "report":[  
              {  
                  "desc":"REJECTED",
                  "status":"16",
                  "number":"91XXXXXXXXXX",
                  "date":"2015-06-10 17:09:32.0"
              },
              {  
                  "desc":"REJECTED",
                  "status":"16",
                  "number":"91XXXXXXXXXX",
                  "date":"2015-06-10 17:09:32.0"
              }
          ],
          "senderId":"tester"
      }
  ]
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: as you can see i am trying to store hooked data into database but failed to do so when contacted to the service provider they said it's coz of 406 error. could u please tell me what are the things i need to add in my myphp.php file to solve this problem?

Comment: Failed to do what exactly? To receive the data? Or to insert it to database? Or to send a response back to service provider?

Comment: sorry for my bad english. failed to receive data.

Comment: You haven't given any exact error or issue so I'm not sure where your problem lies, but you should make sure a header `Content-Type` is set; and better use `file_get_contents('php://input');` instead of `$request = $_REQUEST["data"];`, you can try [this code](https://codeshare.io/axLXLL) once and let me know if it works: https://codeshare.io/axLXLL

Comment: @please guide me how to set a header in my php code.

Comment: added the header but still can't receieve data. is it coz of server mod2 security.